# Moving adMob ads to the bottom of Relative Layout crashes the app

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I'm implementing adMob ads to my app and I have a small problem with it. When I add the AdMob ads to my app and they're automatically positioned on the top of the layout it all works good. But when I try to move the ad down to the bottom of the relative layout the app crashes.

Logcat:

```
08-14 13:57:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(4141): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-14 13:57:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(4141): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad/com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad.TabLayout}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad/com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Chronometer
08-14 13:57:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(4141):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
08-14 13:57:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(4141):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
08-14 13:57:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(4141):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-14 13:57:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(4141):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
08-14 13:57:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(4141):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-14 13:57:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(4141):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-14 13:57:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(4141):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-14 13:57:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(4141):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 13:57:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(4141):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-14 13:57:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(4141):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-14 13:57:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(4141):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-14 13:57:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(4141):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-14 13:57:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(4141): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad/com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Chronometer
08-14 13:57:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(4141):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
08-14 13:57:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(4141):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2054)
08-14 13:57:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(4141):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
08-14 13:57:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(4141):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
08-14 13:57:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(4141):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:749)
08-14 13:57:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(4141):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
08-14 13:57:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(4141):     at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:240)
08-14 13:57:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(4141):     at com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad.TabLayout.onCreate(TabLayout.java:33)
08-14 13:57:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(4141):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
08-14 13:57:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(4141):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-14 13:57:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(4141):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
08-14 13:57:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(4141):     ... 11 more
08-14 13:57:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(4141): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Chronometer
08-14 13:57:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(4141):     at com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:71)
08-14 13:57:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(4141):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
08-14 13:57:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(4141):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-14 13:57:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(4141):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
08-14 13:57:53.126: E/AndroidRuntime(4141):     ... 21 more
```

I tested it, and everytime I implement ads, they work until I move them down to the bottom of the relative layout. What could be the problem? I can see from the logcat that there's a problem with ToggleButton so I even tried moving the togglebutton around the layout but it doesn't fix anything.

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads">

<Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/timer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Chronometer" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/recButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/timer"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:onClick="recordBtnClick"
    android:src="@drawable/record_btn" />

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/tBtn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textOff="Touch to record"
    android:textOn="Touch to record" />

<com.google.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, 3F40A7AF85746C87"
    app:adSize="BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="a1520b668ee78d8" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: Why do you have this in the layout: `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`?

Comment: @g00dy I don't know, looks like it came automatically when I was re-positioning the ad. I removed it but it still crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a class cast exception at line 71 of your code. If line 71 of your code is

```
  chTimer = (Chronometer)findViewById(R.id.timer);
```

as you indicated in your response to Arshad then you have a confused build environment where the generated resource ids are not what you think they are.

Do a **clean build** so that the resource ids are regenerated.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your MainActivity.java file on Line No. 71. You are passing the Chronometer id into the ImageButton. That's why you are getting a Class cast exception

Comment: This is my line 71 'chTimer = (Chronometer)findViewById(R.id.timer);' I don't know why this would have anything to do with admob

Comment: Please check if the object chTimer is an object of Chronometer.

Comment: Yes, it is. It's declared as a global variable 'Chronometer chTimer;'

Comment: Your logcat states that you have made a casting error that you are passing the Chronometer id into the ImageButton. Please check your TableLayout class. There are two class cast exceptions in your logcat. Now if the MainActivity is fine, then it might be in the TableLayout class.